# split a string on a - delimiter in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, split

How do I split a string basis on a delimiter in Bash?

I have string stored in a variable as shown below:

```
DATA="111111-777777-Hello"
```

Now I would like to split above string on `-` delimiter and store two numbers in two different variables.

```
NUMBER1="111111"
NUMBER2="777777"
```

If NUMBER1 and NUMBER2 is an empty string and not a number then exit out of the script with non zero status code.

Comment: Using all-caps names for your own variables in shell is bad form. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html -- all-caps names are used for environment variables with meaning to the operating system and shell itself (setting a shell variable with the same name will overwrite a like-named environment variable even without any attempt to `export` it). Steering clear of that namespace prevents overwriting something important by accident.

Comment: BTW, since you have this tagged bash, I gave an answer that works in bash -- if you want something that works with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang or when run as `sh yourscript` instead of `bash yourscript`, that would be different.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on all caps name. Will look into that. Yeah bash is what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IFS=- read -r number1 number2 _ <<<"$DATA"
[[ $number1 && $number2 ]] || { echo "Initial columns not read" >&2; exit 1; }
[[ $number1$number2 = *[![:digit:]]* ]] && { echo "Values are not numeric" >&2; exit 1; }

echo "Number 1 is $number1"
echo "Number 2 is $number2"
```

---

Setting `IFS` to your delimiter on the same line as the `read` command (with no separator such as `;` between) scopes it to that single `read` operation, so it won't modify the shell's behavior elsewhere in the script.

Note the `_` as an extra argument to `read` -- the rest of the line is stored there, preventing it from being appended to `number2`.

Comment: thanks how do we check whether those are just number only and not an empty string as well and then basis on that exit out of the script with non zero status code?

Comment: Amended to demonstrate same.

Comment: ...also amended to check for any non-numeric digits.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to split it into an array use this

```
split() {
    #  split string separator
    #  split a string into an array
    #  the array returned will be newArray
    #  on error return status is 1
    #  usage:- split bash?ksh?zsh?dash ? >>> returns an array of 3 elements bash[0] ksh[1] zsh[2] dash[3]
   local string="${1}" separator="${2}"
   declare cutOneCharacter;
   declare tempvar
   # appending $sepeartor to the ending of $string
   # bacon?tuna?hamburger ? >>>>> if not appeneded the result will be>>>>>> bacon tuna //o_O where is hamburger ?
   # if appeneded the result will be >>>> bacon tuna harmburger 
   string="$string$separator"
   [[ ${newArray[@]} ]] && unset newArray
   splitUsage() {
     echo  "Usage: split string separator" >&2
   }

  (( "${#@}" != "2" )) && splitUsage && return 1;
  while [ -n "${string}" ];do
    cutOneCharacter=$( printf "%c" "$string" )
    if [[ "${cutOneCharacter}" == "${separator}" ]];then
        newArray+=( "${tempvar}" )
        unset tempvar;
    else
        tempvar+="${cutOneCharacter}"
    fi
    string=${string#*?}
  done
  echo"${newArray[@]}"
  return 0;
}
```

[more details are here](https://github.com/zombieleet/cash/blob/master/cash.bash)

Comment: What value does this implementation add over  `split() { IFS="$2" read -r -a newArray <<<"$1"; }`?

Answer (score 0):

With bash, manipulating IFS

```
data="111111-777777-Hello"
mapfile -t data < <(IFS=-; printf "%s\n" $data)  # variable is not quoted
echo "${data[0]}"    # 111111
echo "${data[1]}"    # 777777
```

Don't use ALLCAPS variable names -- leave them reserved for the shell.

Comment: I'd suggest turning off globbing inside the subshell before expanding `$data` unquoted, just to be safe. (If `nullglob` were set, and the `Hello` section contained `[]`s, a `*`, &c., that could null the whole expansion result).